# selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: missing 'ELEMENT' error when switching frame in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, invalidargumentexception

I am trying to switch to an iframe in selenium (Python).  Though, no matter what I try, I keep getting an error.

```
iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
print(len(iframes))
    for iframe in iframes:
        if 'ontouchmove' in iframe:
            print(iframe)
            driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

This produces the error -

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: missing 'ELEMENT'
```

I have also tried this -

```
iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
print(len(iframes))
counter = 0
for iframe in iframes:
    if 'ontouchmove' in iframe:
        print(iframe)
        driver.switch_to.frame(counter)
    counter += 1
```

this produces the error -

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: frame.setAttribute is not a function
```

I am not really sure what else I can do here, kind of lost.. any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

```
iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
print(len(iframes))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframes[0])
```

This produces error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: missing 'ELEMENT'
```

Answer (score 0):

This `if 'ontouchmove' in iframe` will not work since `iframe` here is a web element, it is not a string but a web element object. So checking for text string in a web element is an invalid action.
This `driver.switch_to.frame(counter)` will not work as well since `driver.switch_to.frame()` intended to accept a web element as a parameter, not an `int` primitive number.
I'm not sure about the correct code that will work for you since I can't see the web page you are working on, I can only guess the following:
You can switch to those iframes and once you are inside them you can validate presence of element containing the desired text there. Something like this:

```py
iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
print(len(iframes))
for iframe in iframes:
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    text_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(),"ontouchmove")]')
    if text_elements: #list is non-empty, element found
            print("Element found!!!")
    else:
        driver.switch_to.default_content() #element not found, switching back to default content
```

Comment: `driver.switch_to.frame(iframes[0])` even If ignore the for loop and just try this, I met with the same error.  Also, `if 'ontouchmove' in iframe:` is behaving correctly and returns the proper iframe.

Comment: If I do `print(type(iframes[0]))` it returns a `dict`.

Comment: Hm... Can you try my updated solution?

Comment: same error as I had, `driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)` produces error `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: missing 'ELEMENT'`

Comment: What gives you `print(len(iframes))`?

Comment: 10. I added the most basic test case to my original post, just taking the first iframe found, same error.

Comment: Are there all iframes on the same level or some of them nested inside other iframes?

Comment: They are all iframes on the same level.  All iframes are within the same div, I am counting exactly 10, looking at the page source code.  Which matches with the iframes count.

Comment: In case the first iframe gives the same error it sounds strange. Need to actually debug that...

Comment: Is it possible to get a reference to an element within a visible iframe without switching to it to find it?  Because in the end, all I have to do is `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)` on the element.  And I can locate the element by searching for `aria-label='Press & Hold'`

Comment: AFAIK you can not do it with Selenium. Maybe with some JavaScript, however I'm not familiar with such option.

Answer (score 0):

*`'ontouchmove'`* is a *string* where as [*iframe*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478) is a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139). So instead of the *WebElement* you should be looking for the *string* within the **value** of the ***attributes*** of the *WebElement*.

- Looking for the string *ontouchmove* within the *WebElement* ***id***:

  ```
  iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
  print(len(iframes))
      for iframe in iframes:
          if 'ontouchmove' in iframe.get_attribute("id"):
              print(iframe)
              driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
  ```
- Looking for the string *ontouchmove* within the *WebElement* ***class***:

  ```
  iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
  print(len(iframes))
      for iframe in iframes:
          if 'ontouchmove' in iframe.get_attribute("class"):
              print(iframe)
              driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
  ```
- Looking for the string *ontouchmove* within the *WebElement* ***title***:

  ```
  iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
  print(len(iframes))
      for iframe in iframes:
          if 'ontouchmove' in iframe.get_attribute("title"):
              print(iframe)
              driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
  ```

Comment: `driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')` is returning a list of dicts.  I think some security that is placed on the site.

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.